# Can not apply yum update or install anything

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

After creating an EC2 instance on AWS, i have connected to the server using SSH ( PEM file ) and i am trying to install Cpanel on the server but i am getting this error, while just trying to update or install anything.

My command :

```
 yum update
```

Error i am getting:

```
amzn2extra-docker                                                                                      | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-epel                                                                                        | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-kernel-5.10                                                                                 | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                   |  14 kB  00:00:00
remi-safe                                                                                              | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
http://r.vestacp.com/cmmnt//x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.


One of the configured repositories failed (Vesta - cmmnt),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

  1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

  2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
     upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
     distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
     packages for the previous distribution release still work).

  3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
         yum --disablerepo=vesta ...

  4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
     will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
     again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

         yum-config-manager --disable vesta
     or
         subscription-manager repos --disable=vesta

  5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
     Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
     so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
     slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
     compromise:

         yum-config-manager --save --setopt=vesta.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from vesta: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://r.vestacp.com/cmmnt//x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

P.S i am using as a Root user.

Software Version:  Amazon Linux 2

Comment: Please Google the text `http://r.vestacp.com/cmmnt/` .... to know that this address has been invalid since ~Aug 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the options that the error suggested, but non of them worked, here is how i solved this

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
```

then

```
rm vesta.repo
```

Now Yum update and installing any package is working.

Answer (score 0):

might be that the url of the vesta repo is incorrect.
Anyway, if you dont need it, you can remove it, just as you did.
But you can also just disable that problematic repo:
`sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/vesta.repo`